# Find branches stemming from commit

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I want to be able to see which branches are based on a certain commit. Given a repository:

```
A--------B-----C-----------D (master)
 `-E (B1)      |`--F (B2)   `-H (B4)
                `--G (B3)
```

How do I see branches stemming from commit `C`? I need a list of at least `B2` and `B3`, but if `master` is also included in the output that's okay. I would prefer if `B4` isn't included.

Comment: You better define your goal formally (a single example is open to multiple interpretations). Better, still, explain what you need this for.

Comment: By definition, the C commit is on the following branches: master, B2, B3, B4.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
git branch --contains <commit-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want see which branch or tag refer to  you can

```
git log -1 <commit-id> --simplify-by-decoration

--simplify-by-decoration
       Commits that are referred by some branch or tag are selected.
```

If you want see which branch contain  you can

```
git branch (-a) --contains <commit-id>
```